# Send CAN form error frames to test device with CAPL

Tags: can-bus, capl, canalyzer

I would like to send form error frames to a device, but I can't figure out how to do that (or a crc error, ack error, etc) with CAPL in the CAPL browser. I think I have to add something like `errorFrame error` in the `Variables {}` section, but whatever I do the CAPL browser keeps complaining ("parse error").

I can send stuff error through the following code:

```
on key 'e' {
  output(CAN1.errorFrame;
}
```

The documentation says that `errorFrame.ErrorCode` has the following options:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

long canOutputErrorFrame(errorFrame, long dominant, long recessive);